# how to set the whole back ground of col-sm-1 to #F7F7F7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my website uses bootstrap grid system of `col-sm-1/col-sm-9/col-sm-2`. And I want to the whole background of col-sm-1 to be #F7F7F7. Thing is I want it to be like the far left side of reddit [image]

but when I tried to manipulate my web, I see only the div that has content on col-sm-1 changes its color.

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <div class="row-fluid">

  <h5 class="tag-name"></h>
  </div>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}

    {% if following %}
  <h5 class="tag-named"><em>follow</em></h5>
  <div class="tagging">
  <div class="tab-pane{% if active_tab == 'connections' %} active{% endif %}" id="connections">
        {% for a in following %}
<li style="padding:0.01em; list-style-type: square;"><a id="following-link" href="{{ a.get_absolute_url }}">{{ a }}</a></li> 
<br />
        {% endfor %}

</div>
</div>
   {% else %}
  <p class="tag-named" style="font-size:12px; text-align:left;"><em>enter <a href="main/search">following</a>community <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
hello</em></p>
    {% endif %}

{% else %}
<p class="tag-named" style="font-size:12px; text-align:left;"><em>now <a href="/accounts/signin/">login</a></em>
</p>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

please ignore django template language {{}}, as this needs to be done with awesome css.

Comment: why do you have a `row-fluid` inside of the col? yet no new grid? Also just give your column a `class` and add `css` for the class

Comment: @JanR, opps my bad thanks for catching that. yeah I tried that but that only works for the div that has content. I tried height:100% but it won't work

Comment: I think this can be best accomplished using a background image, did you try it?